# strange result when trying to increment a n php cookie

Tags: php, cookies

can someone please how what hell this

cookie stops at 2 ?

```
<?php 
if (isset($_COOKIE["count"]))
{
    $cookie = ++$_COOKIE['count'];
}
else {
  echo "Welcome guest!<br>";
  setcookie("count", 1, time()+3600);
}

ECHO $cookie;

?>
```

thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$cookie = ++$_COOKIE['count'];` is only called once. If `$_COOKIE[count]` has a numerical value, `$cookie` will store that value plus 1.

Also, the following is not strictly correct:

```
echo "Welcome guest!<br>";
setcookie("count", 1, time()+3600);
```

You cannot call an `echo` before a header. I recommend you change it to this:

```
setcookie("count", 1, time()+3600);
echo "Welcome guest!<br>";
```

Comment: ok lets make it more simple for me :-)
i want to count how much time the user refresh the page 
using cookies only, can i do that?

Comment: Ah, I understand your question now. It looks like jasir answered it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update a cookie that way. However you can overwrite it.

[See setcookie for more info.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

If you set a cookie, it won't retrieved until the next request and so the data won't be present in $_COOKIE.

So setting a cookie and accessing it cannot be in same instance. You need to redirect or refresh after setting it. 
Simply use `setcookie()` to increment.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change cookie value by incrementing $_COOKIE[xxx], you have to use `setcookie()` function for that. This will work:

```
<?php
$cookie = isset($_COOKIE["count"]) ? $_COOKIE["count"] : 0;
setcookie('count', $cookie + 1, time()+3600);
ECHO $cookie;
```

Answer (score -2):

to increment you place the ++ after the string, not before it.

Comment: `Pre-increment` and `post-increment` are both perfectly valid - http://prototype.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php

Comment: I've never seen pre-incrementing before. Seems pretty useless in this case though.